Is it better to auto open a dialog/sidepanel when redirecting from an email link?
We have a situation where our application sends an email with an activation link to the users. This link redirects to the activation page of our application where they need to enter some additional information. The UI for these extra information is presented via right sidepanel, which appears when the user clicks on "Activate" CTA button (this UI does not have any other CTA button). So our team is internally debating about one of the two approaches:

Should we automatically open the sidepanel when the user is redirected to the app from the activation email link?
Redirect to the page and let the user click on the "Activate" CTA button which then opens the sidepanel?

Which one of these would be a better UX experience for end users, and why?
Edit:
Instead of sidepanels, the UI can be thought in terms of modals as well. The situation still applies, and the question still remains that - Should the modal be auto displayed, or should the user be allowed to trigger it manually?

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but why do you use a sidepanel for data required to complete the activation ("they need to enter")?
In my view, a sidepanel presents additional information, not required for the typical usage of a page. When your activation procedure requires the data in the sidepanel, that creates a mismatch between the process and the controls used, I feel. So I would put all mandatory information on the main page. After all, the page is for activation - there should not be too much additional information on it.
Regarding your question of showing the data immediately vs. after "Activate":
When I press "Activate", I expect activation - I do not expect further required inputs. If you (or your team) favors (2) because they fear people are put off by showing all mandatory input fields initially, consider reducing the amount of mandatory input. And make sure everyone understands why each single field is actually required for their purpose (as opposed to your company wanting to collect data).

sidepanels is used throughout the application, and the UI has been designed with it in mind. We don't have much say in that. The question still applies if we think in terms of modals instead of sidepanels - should the modal be auto-displayed or should the user be allowed to trigger it manually?

My argument (when I click the email link to activate, I want to activate, not click an additional button to go where I can activate) applies to both the sidepanel or the modal.
